# Pagination in relations using 'with'

Tags: laravel

I have some trouble with pagination. I need to take only one category with movies and paginate it. Now I write some code, but I don't think it's optimized.

```
$category = Category::with(['movies' => function ($query) {
            $query->orderBy('id', 'desc')->paginate(18);
        }])->where('slug', $slug)->first();

        $catMoviesPaginate = $category->movies()->paginate(18);
```

Comment: The first query is literally not doing anything since you override it with the relationship call

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with lazy loading as here I mention the code which can help to you.

```
$category = Category::where('slug', $slug)->first();
$movies= $category->movies()->paginate(18); //lazy loding.
return view('example', compact('category', 'movies'));
```

You can render the pagination in view file as well.

```
@foreach ($movies as $movie)
    {{ $movie->id }}
@endforeach

{!! $movies->render() !!}
```

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient way would be to create an inversed relation in movies for categories. Then you query the movies in X category by slug. You should end up with something like this

```
Movies::whereHas('categories', function($q) use($slug) {
  $q->where('slug', $slug)
})->paginate(18);
```

You can take it a step further and create a scope in the Movies model to simplify your code. With the proper scope it can be as simple as `Movies::inCategory($slug)->paginate(18)`